# phpmyadmin.conf and apache.conf missing

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, apache2

When trying to start apache with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I get the error

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 260 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open
configuration file /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
...fail!
```

What should I do? When reading on the internet I should also have a file called apache.conf in /etc/phpmyadmin but I don't.

Comment: I do not have any sample files. Currently, no matter how I change things it is either apache.conf missing in phpmyadmin or phpmyadmin.conf missing in apache2/conf.d

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/phpmyadmin.html
http://packages.debian.org/experimental/all/phpmyadmin/filelist

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1613290.html

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I'm not using php at all. It seems to me that having a php admin file shouldn't be necessary just to run the server.

Comment: @PiotrWadas shouldn't be dismissing this problem. Not everyone in the world is using only php with their apache instance.

Answer (score 12):

Just ran into this issue on Debian 7, installer and dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin create a broken link "/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf" which points to the missing file "../../phpmyadmin/apache.conf".  Had to pull a copy off an older installation, posting below.  Piotr, your comments were not useful, don't pollute.

## phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_value include_path .
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
    AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

Comment: this is a great config file. I've tried so many in the past, none of them worked properly.

Comment: I had `<VirtualHost *:80...` with Alias inside in phpmyadmin.conf. Default server got phpmyadmin's config instead of 000-default.conf. Removing all lines except Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin fix it.

Comment: had a missing phpmyadmin.conf after installing phpmyadmin using this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04 , but this config file worked, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the folder /etc/apache2/conf.d exists, if not create it.

```
mkdir -p /etc/apache2/conf.d/
```

Apache2.conf file includes all files from this folder into the config, if this folder does not exist it shows an error.

```
user@host:~$ cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf | grep conf.d
Include conf.d/
```

From: https://askubuntu.com/questions/365454/apache2-error-could-not-open-configuration-file-etc-apache2-conf-d-no-such-fi

Then replace this line:

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
```

with this one:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
```

in the apache2.conf file.

Sorted it out for me.